# How do I integrate user information into my Facebook application?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I wrote an application in Javascript that I put on facebook and would now like to integrate user information into the gameplay. I would like it to be similar to the way Words with Friends works, where the users' name and profile picture information are used to display the scores. To work best with the way my application works, being able to set the name and picture as variables seem to me to be the best way of doing this. Ideally I would also like to incorporate a way to select from a menu of the users friends which friend they want to challenge and send a request, and also record the users win/loss statistics. I have searched around and have not been able to find any guides on how to do this. If someone could point me to one or provide me with the code to do this that would be really great. I am somewhat new to programming and entirely new to Facebook applications.

Here is a link to what I have so far: https://apps.facebook.com/dotsandboxesgame.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big topic and requires you to dive in the graph API which I assume you've looked at. In case you haven't here is the link

https://graph.facebook.com/

Basically, you need to ask a facebook user for permission to do certain things. What you want to be able to do with their account will be in line with what your application does. When a user accepts these permissions, you will have an access token that you can then use in a query string to query the graph API for any data available about that person (limited by what permissions you asked for from them).

It's then up to your code to interpret that data (JSON or XML) and then display it, interact with it etc.

Be warned, the Facebook API documentation can be quite vague. It is also hard to find certain topics, and Facebook constantly deprecates things. When they deprecate things they do tend to give a good amount of leniency for developers to update their code however.

Best of luck.